# Code using MPI and working in Linux with OpenMPI doesn't compile in Windows using MSMPI

Tags: visual-studio, ms-mpi

I am trying to compile a program in C using MSMPI in Windows 7. The program compiles and runs fine in Linux with OpenMPI. However in doesn't compile with the MS compiler in Visual Studio 2010. The moment I uncomment the line "MPI_Init()" I am strating to get a large number of errors and the message

"Error  207 error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation"

The first offending line is this

"myObj *a[5] = {NULL};"

with an error message

"Error  104 error C2059: syntax error : '{'"

The compiler complains about an unexpected right curly bracket "{". With the MPI_Init statement commented out the code compiles fine, but of course doesn't use MSMPI. Here is a snippet of the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include "more_header_files.h" 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
   MPI_Status status;
   int my_rank, numProc;

   MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank );
   MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numProc );

   myObj *a[5] = {NULL};
```

Is there a solution other than installing MinGW and compiling with GCC (which might not work either)?

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS 2010 when I posted the question. Migrating to VS 2013 solved the compilation problem. Unfortunately, now the executable crashes with no useful information. Same exact code works fine in Linux using OpenMPI.